# Get first element of Series without knowing the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, head

Is there any way to access the first element of a Series without knowing its index?

Let's say I have the following Series:

```
import pandas as pd

key='MCS096'
SUBJECTS = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": pd.Series([146], index=[145]),
        "study": pd.Series(["MCS"], index=[145]),
        "center": pd.Series(["Mag"], index=[145]),
        "initials": pd.Series(["MCS096"], index=[145]),
    }
)
```

Print out `SUBJECTS`:

```
print(SUBJECTS[SUBJECTS.initials==key]['ID'])
>>> 145    146
>>> Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

How can I get the value 146 here without using index 145?

Comment: All it takes is `(SUBJECTS[SUBJECTS.initials==key]['ID']).values[0]`

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Use iloc to access by position (rather than label):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], ['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   A  B
a  1  2
b  3  4

In [13]: df.iloc[0]  # first row in a DataFrame
Out[13]: 
A    1
B    2
Name: a, dtype: int64

In [14]: df['A'].iloc[0]  # first item in a Series (Column)
Out[14]: 1
```

Comment: How is this done with a Series rather than a DataFrame. Do we have to convert the Series first?

Comment: Sorry, I was using this in another project and ```df['A'].iloc[0]``` gave me an error but ```df.iloc[0]['A']``` did not for some reason.

Comment: @sobio35 yes, that should actually not work, because `df['A']` creates a Series and on this iloc won't work. But the other way around, as described by you, it works, as iloc is performed on the whole df and then Series ['A'] is selected.

Comment: if you want to do this with a series you can also do: `ser.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)` ; `ser[0]`

Comment: @GenericWevers Why do you think `iloc` doesn't work on a `Series`? In this particular answer there is an example where it does.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins At the time I tried it didn't work. I tried today and  your right.

Comment: This will only work as long as the DataFrame/Series is not empty. Any suggestion on making it "null resistant", without a helper variable?