# Pandas get the row ID based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
Date          best    a    b    c    d
1990-01-01    a       5    4    7    2
1991-01-02    c       10   1    2    0
1992-01-03    d       2    1    4    12
1993-01-04    a       5    8    11   6
```

I wish to get the row ID where `df['Date' == '1992-01-03']`.

The expected return is `2`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do that, you need to access the `DataFrame`'s index and obtain its id. Following the explanations of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21800319/3921457 and assuming your object is named `df` you can do something like:

```py
ids = df.index[df['Date'] == '1992-01-03'].tolist()
print(ids)
# [2]
```

If `Date` is already the index of the `DataFrame`, you can change to numeric indexing simply typing: `df = df.reset_index()`.

Comment: thanks for your kind advice. Is it possible to return the value in integer data type?

Comment: To do that you can simply access the first element of the list i.e. `ids[0]` (or use `.iloc[0] as described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/24273130/3921457) but you should consider the "not found" case. In any case, it's possible to obtain more than one coincidence, sou maybe you need to implement some kind of logic to pick one of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `np.where`:

```
np.where(df.Date=='1992-01-03')
```