# How to get first three elements from a (pandas) series?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have to count the occurrences of all characters in a string, order them in descending order, and print the first three character with the number of occurrences.
Example: `phrase = 'abraccbb'`.
Here `'a'` and `'c'` occur twice, while `'b'` occurs 3 times and `'r'` once.
I want the output to be:

```
b    3
a    2
c    2
```

I have tried the code `pd.Series(list(phrase)).value_counts()`, which gives the output for all characters and in descending order. However, the problem is that I don't know how to extract the first three values.

Comment: use `pd.Series(list(phrase)).value_counts().iloc[:3]`

Comment: Can also use a list slice `pd.Series(list(phrase)).value_counts()[:3]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first element of Series without knowing the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273130/get-first-element-of-series-without-knowing-the-index)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use:

`Series.head(3)`

Comment: Please describe the effect of what you propose and explain why that helps to solve the problem. Try for [answer].